# Check if column value is greater than the max between pandas column and python variable

Tags: python, pandas

I have a dataframe which looks like this

```
pd.DataFrame({'A': ['C1', 'C2', 'C3', 'C4', 'C5', 'C6', 'C7'],
  ...:                    'x': [2, 2, 3, 2, 3, 1, 3],
  ...:                    'maxValue_1': [2, 1, 2, 3, 4, 2, 1]})
Out[7]: 
    A  x  maxValue_1
0  C1  2           2
1  C2  2           1
2  C3  3           2
3  C4  2           3
4  C5  3           4
5  C6  1           2
6  C7  3           1

maxValue_2 = 2
```

I need to check whether column 'x' is equal or greater than the max(df.maxValue_1, maxValue_2)

Resulting dataframe should look like this.

```
    A  x  maxValue_1  result
0  C1  2           2   True
1  C2  2           1   True
2  C3  3           2   True
3  C4  2           3   False
4  C5  3           4   False
5  C6  1           2   False
6  C7  3           1   True
```

How can I code this in an efficient manner without having to add variable 'maxValue_2' to the dataframe?

Comment: `df[x'].gt(df['maxValue_1']) & df['x'].gt(max_Value_2)`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
df['result'] = df['x'] >= np.maximum(df['maxValue_1'], maxValue_2)
print(df)
```

Prints:

```
    A  x  maxValue_1  result
0  C1  2           2    True
1  C2  2           1    True
2  C3  3           2    True
3  C4  2           3   False
4  C5  3           4   False
5  C6  1           2   False
6  C7  3           1    True
```

Answer (score 3):

```
df['result'] = df.apply(lambda row: row.x >= max(row.maxValue_1, maxValue_2), axis=1)
```

Answer (score 0):

I have found that the `apply` method is extremely useful for this type of problem. We want to apply some function, `model_map` to the dataframe.

```
def model_map(row):
    if row['x'] >= max(df.maxValue_1, maxValue_2):
        return True
    else:
        return False
    
df['result'] = df.apply(lambda row : model_map(row), axis=1)
```

This will give you a nice way to create a column based on a function.

Comment: While this code may answer the question, providing additional context regarding why and/or how this code answers the question improves its long-term value.

Comment: Thanks for the advice. I provided detail @iknow

Answer (score 0):

To accomplish this, we’ll use numpy’s built-in `where()` function. This function takes three arguments in sequence: the condition we’re testing for, the value to assign to our new column if that condition is true, and the value to assign if it is false. It looks like this:

```
np.where(condition, value if condition is true, value if condition is false)
```

And the function `maximum()` to get the max of the giving values:

```
df['result'] = np.where(df['x']>= np.maximum(df['maxValue_1'], maxValue_2) , True, False)
```

**OUTPUT:**

```
    A  x  maxValue_1  result
0  C1  2           2    True
1  C2  2           1    True
2  C3  3           2    True
3  C4  2           3   False
4  C5  3           4   False
5  C6  1           2   False
6  C7  3           1    True
```

Answer (score 0):

You can also define the series of maxes through set comprehension and compare to the `x` series like so

```py
df['result'] = df['x'] >= [ max(max_value2, row['maxValue_1']) for idx, row in df.iterrows()]
```